# How can I store time zone information in an Outlook Contact?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts, time-zone

Is there a way to store the time zone of an individual in an Outlook 2010 Contact?

This would be useful for making sure that I am not calling them or scheduling a meeting for after business hours.

Comment: I know you can specify time zones in scheduled meetings but other than that not much to work with

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is built in functionality for that but you might find [this plug-in](http://www.ablebits.com/outlook-sender-timezone/index.php) helpful (if you are willing to pay for it).